# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive on client browser why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

**Problem :-**

Here problem with my WCF data service.

it is working properly on my local server and it is also working fine on browser.

but i am getting problem in only one **URL** and this URL is also working fine on my local server but it is giving me error when i executing on client browser.

so i have only problem with one URL And this URL is also working locally. I refer lots of answer related this error on stack-overflow but i could not get my answer.

**My code :-**

```
SupplierProjectEntities de = new SupplierProjectEntities(new Uri("xyz/url"));
        protected void BindData()
        {
            cleardrp();
            var city = from t in de.State_City_View select t;
            drpfilter.DataTextField = "City_Id";
            drpfilter.DataValueField = "City_Id";
            drpfilter.DataSource = city;
            drpfilter.DataBind();
            var lis = from t in de.State_City_View select t;
            grdCity.DataSource = lis.ToList();
            grdCity.DataBind();
        }
```

i am getting Error in drpfilter.DataBind(); line as above

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

**Error Found in Result View :-**

and when i am View result of city object on that time i am getting below error.

> Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation
>   timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function
>   evaluation.

**Note**

it is working on local server.but only one URL have a problem on client Computer Browser.

if you know about this error so please help me to short out this problem.

thanking in advance guys.

Comment: no i am fetching only 17 record from view.

Comment: yes, but are those 17 entities connected to a large object graph?

Comment: id=1 , city=Ahemedabad, stateid=1 , statename=Gujrat like this i am getting only 17 record which contents only four columns.

Comment: and it is working properly on local server.

Comment: Are you using WCF data services?

Comment: yes i am  using wcf data service.